# Why does my setTimeout function return “window” instead of my object’s name property?

Tags: javascript

```
function Person(name) {
this.name = name;
}

Person.prototype.showName = function() {
alert(this.name);
}


var mike = new Person("mike");
mike.showName();  


window.name = "window"; 
setTimeout(mike.showName, 5000);
```

When

```
setTimeout(mike.showName, 5000)
```

is executed, why is the result "window"? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Paul, 
Because setTimeout is run in the window scope. The method can also be called via window.setTimeout(). Thus, when mike.showName is called, this refers to the window object, not your Person object.

You could use a wrapper function to solve this problem:

```
  window.setTimeout(function()
  {
  mike.showName();
  }, 5000);
```

Also read: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/this.html

Answer (score 1):

You need to capture the scope into an anonymous function or setTimeout will run in the window scope:

```
setTimeout(function() { mike.showName() }, 5000);
```

Answer (score 1):

Code executed by `setTimeout()` is run in a separate execution context to the function from which it was called. As a consequence, the this keyword for the called function will be set to the window (or global) object, it will not be the same as the this value for the function that called setTimeout. This issue is explained in more detail in the JavaScript reference.

Use `setTimeout('mike.showName()', 5000);` instead.